# How can I start to mine?

Tags: client, miner-configuration, mining-software

I want to begin to mine on a computer, I know that it is not efficient but I want to do some experiments and tests for a project.

I tried all programs in the list https://www.bitcoinmining.com/bitcoin-mining-software/ but none wanted to start to mine

Can anyone recommend me a software that can mine from a dektop?

Comment: It doesn't appear that that site lists any mining programs. Could you clarify what you've tried?

Comment: sorry list is here https://www.bitcoinmining.com/bitcoin-mining-software/

Comment: I tried https://guiminer.org/ but it is always 0 for mining

Comment: Also similar: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32834/how-do-i-start-mining